# Unreliable Unix Socket Connection

Tags: xcode, macos, sockets, tcp, c++14

I have created a basic client/server c++ socket program. I can write integers over the socket reliably, but when I try to write a string over the socket the receiving end only receives the data about 25% of the time. I have used Wireshark to verify that the data is being sent. I am new to c++ and network programming so any input would be appreciated. The code is below.

```
class compressionServer{
    int                 PORT = 4000;
    int                 LISTEN_QUEUE = 1024;
    int                 sock;
    int                 conn;
    struct sockaddr_in  socketAddress;
    int                 receivedMagicData[8+1];
    int                 receivedStatusCode[2];
    int                 receivedPayloadLength[2];
    char                receivedCompressionData[2048];
    int                 requestCode = 0;
    int                 payloadLength;
    uint32_t            inBytes = 0;
    uint32_t            outBytes = 0;
    double              compressionRatio = 0;
    string              dataToCompress;

public:
    void start(){
        if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
            printf("Socket Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        bzero(&socketAddress, sizeof(socketAddress));
        socketAddress.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        socketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        socketAddress.sin_port        = htons(PORT);
        int enable = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0){ // so we can rebind quickly while testing
            printf("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
        }
        if(::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &socketAddress, sizeof(socketAddress)) < 0){
            printf("Bind Error\n");
            std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }


        if(listen(sock, LISTEN_QUEUE) < 0){
            printf("Listen Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        for ( ; ; ) {
            if((conn = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL)) < 0){
                printf("Accept Error");
                exit(1);
            }
            ssize_t n;
            if((n = read(conn, receivedMagicData, 8)) > 0){
                int magicWord = ntohl(*receivedMagicData);

                if(magicWord == 53545259){
                    std::cout << "DOES NOT MATCH" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if((n = read(conn, receivedPayloadLength, 2)) > 0){
                payloadLength = ntohs(*receivedPayloadLength);

                std::cout << "payloadLength = " << std::hex << payloadLength << std::endl;
            }
            if((n = read(conn, receivedStatusCode, 2)) > 0){
                requestCode = ntohs(*receivedStatusCode);

                std::cout << "requestCode = " << std::hex << requestCode << std::endl;
            }
            while((n = read(conn, receivedCompressionData, 2048)) > 0){
                receivedCompressionData[n] = 0;
                cout << "data: " << receivedCompressionData << endl;
                dataToCompress = receivedCompressionData;
                if(strlen(receivedCompressionData) > 0){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (close(conn) < 0){
            printf("Close Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
};
```

The server class essential is expecting to receive 12 bytes of data as the header and after that up to 2048 bytes as the characters. This is the part only coming through a fraction of the time.

```
class compressionClient{

public:
    void start(std::string  ipAddr){
        int                 MAX_LINE = 4096;
        int                 sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;


        if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
            printf("socket error");
            exit(1);
        }

        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port   = htons(4000);


        if (inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddr.c_str(), &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0){
            printf("inet_pton error for %s", ipAddr.c_str());
            exit(1);
        }


        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0){
            printf("connect error");
            exit(1);
        }

        long headerHex = htonl(0x53545259);
        long header2Hex = htonl(0x31300034);

        std::cout << "send: " << std::hex << headerHex << std::endl;
        std::cout << "send2: " << std::hex << header2Hex << std::endl;
//server receives this
        if(send(sockfd, (char *) (&headerHex), sizeof(headerHex), 0) < 0){
            printf("Write Error");
            exit(1);
        }
//server receives this too 
        if(send(sockfd, (char *) (&header2Hex), sizeof(header2Hex), 0) < 0){
            printf("Write Error2");
            exit(1);
        }
        char data[100];
        snprintf(data, sizeof(data), "aaabbcddd");
//server only recieves this sometimes
        if(write(sockfd, data, strlen(data)) < 0){
            printf("write error3");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Depending on the size of `long` on your platform, the sender sends either 8 or 16 (`2 * sizeof(long)`) bytes, before sending data. The receiver reads 12 (`8 + 2 + 2`) bytes. That doesn't look right.

Comment: `receivedCompressionData[n] = 0` may exhibit undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun, since `n` may be equal to 2048.

Comment: Thanks, @IgorTandetnik, after reading your comments, I realized I only need to store data in ints. Once I changed headerHex and Header2Hex to ints it went through every time. If you want to write an answer I'll mark it as correct.